# Ifelse does not work inside a function

Tags: r, function, if-statement

I have come across this issue a couple of times, where placing the ifelse statement inside a function always results in the same result.

```
Data$QuarterHour <- ifelse( Data$Minute < 15, return( 1 ),
                                  ifelse( Data$Minute < 30 , return( 2 ),
                                          ifelse( DataFrame$Minute < 45, return( 3 ), return( 4 ) ) ) )
```

This works perfectly fine. However, when I place it into a function. It does not.

```
calculateHourQuarter <- function( aMinute )
{
ifelse( aMinute < 15, return( 1 ),
        ifelse( aMinute < 30 , return( 2 ),
                ifelse( aMinute < 45, return( 3 ), return( 4 ) ) ) )
}

DataFrame$QuarterHour <- calculateHourQuarter( as.numeric( Data$Minute ) )
```

This results in the column being filled with 1's. When I call the function interactively in the console, it produces the right result when I just pass it integer's from the console.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Remove `return` statement from your R clause. An R function terminates when it meets a `return`.

Also, `ifelse` does not want a `return` statement, but only returned **value**. Read `?ifelse` again; the first example for `ifelse` is showing you the correct way to work:

```
x <- c(6:-4)
sqrt(ifelse(x >= 0, x, NA))
```

There is no `return`, right?

---

Finally, `ifelse` is really not designed for nesting (although you can). Using `cut` or `findInterval` instead (the latter better suits your need here as you want integer result):

```
findInterval(aMinute, c(0, 15, 30, 45, 60))
```

Comment: Could also mention `if` and `else`, which is maybe what they wanted here since each of their conditions seems to have a length of one. Oh, never mind, guess they are working with vectors.

Comment: It's worth noting that ifelse has a very peculiar (and often useful) feature, which is that the final outcome has the same dimensions as the boolean statement. This can produce awkward results sometimes if, instead of the above you did: `ifelse(TRUE, x, NA)` which would return 6, not `6:-4`